# Azure Virtual Machine has no endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Im trying to create VM's from a template in my ASP.NET MVC web application. So I wrote an action is structured in 4 steps (I added some comments to make it more understandable)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QuickCreateVM(string VirtualMachineName, string OSImage, string Username, string Password)
{
    string Location = "North Europe";
    string StorageAccountName = "azuremanagersharepoint"; 

    try
    {
        ComputeManagementClient client = new ComputeManagementClient(cloudCredentials);
        string vmName = VirtualMachineName;

        //STEP1:Create Hosted Service 
        //Azure VM must be hosted in a  hosted cloud service. 
        createCloudService(vmName, Location);

        //STEP2:Construct VM Role instance 
        var vmRole = new Role();
        vmRole.RoleType = VirtualMachineRoleType.PersistentVMRole.ToString();
        vmRole.RoleName = vmName;
        vmRole.Label = vmName;
        vmRole.RoleSize = VirtualMachineRoleSize.Small;
        vmRole.ConfigurationSets = new List<ConfigurationSet>();
        vmRole.OSVirtualHardDisk = new OSVirtualHardDisk()
        {
            MediaLink = getVhdUri(string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net/uploads", StorageAccountName)),
            SourceImageName = OSImage
        };

        ConfigurationSet configSet = new ConfigurationSet
        {
            ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.WindowsProvisioningConfiguration,
            EnableAutomaticUpdates = true,
            ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon = false,
            ComputerName = vmName,
            AdminUserName = Username,
            AdminPassword = Password,
            InputEndpoints = new BindingList<InputEndpoint> 
            { 
                new InputEndpoint { LocalPort = 3389, Port = 3389, Name = "Remote Desktop", Protocol = "TCP", EnableDirectServerReturn = true }

            }
        };

        vmRole.ConfigurationSets.Add(configSet);
        vmRole.ResourceExtensionReferences = null;

        //STEP3: Add Role instance to Deployment Parmeters 
        List<Role> roleList = new List<Role>() { vmRole };
        VirtualMachineCreateDeploymentParameters createDeploymentParams = new VirtualMachineCreateDeploymentParameters
        {
            Name = vmName,
            Label = vmName,
            Roles = roleList,
            DeploymentSlot = DeploymentSlot.Production
        };

        //STEP4: Create a Deployment with VM Roles. 
        client.VirtualMachines.CreateDeployment(vmName, createDeploymentParams);
    }
    catch (CloudException e)
    {

        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return View("Panel");
}
```

My problem: It seems like my VM has no endpoint. Although the ConfigurationSet was configured correctly. So, in my code I say

`new InputEndpoint { LocalPort = 3389, Port = 3388, Name = "Remote Desktop", Protocol = "TCP", EnableDirectServerReturn = true }`

But in the azure portal 
[image: No endpoints are configured]
So I'm not able to start the Vm.
Has anyone an idea what I'm missing? Or are there any good tutorials to this topic?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see a problem at a first glance. A way how you can check the whole thing is to go through [Brady Gaster's post](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/announcing-the-general-availability-of-the-microsoft-azure-management-libraries-for-net). He has also some code snipptes available. They are not up-to-date but guide the general direction.

Comment: Im having the same issue, ever find a soloution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had the exact same issue and figured out the problem.

You need to create an additional `ConfigurationSet` with a `ConfigurationSetType` of `ConfigurationSetTypes.NetworkConfiguration`, and then add your endpoints in there.

Something like this:

```
ConfigurationSet networkConfigSet = new ConfigurationSet
{
    ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.NetworkConfiguration,
    InputEndpoints = new BindingList<InputEndpoint> 
    { 
        new InputEndpoint { LocalPort = 3389, Port = 3389, Name = "Remote Desktop", Protocol = "TCP", EnableDirectServerReturn = true }        
    }
};

vmRole.ConfigurationSets.Add(networkConfigSet);
```

See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157194.aspx

...specifically the **ConfigurationSets** section.